# Kinesis Firehose same stream in multiple regions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have an API built using flask which dumps data to s3 using kinesis firehose. So far it is only in one region with load balancer and auto-scaling group containing multiple instances. Now I want to have the flask application in multiple region in order to reduce latency. However, I could find a way to configure Kinesis Firehose stream for different regions. That means, even if I put my application in different regions, Kinesis Firehose will become the bottleneck.

Is it possible to support multiple regions for kinesis firehose and channel the data based on the closest region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the stream using boto3 specify the region. Keep the same stream name but pick different regions each time. If you want to manually do it from the AWS web console then change the region at the top and then create the stream. Keep repeating the process for each region.